# ArcGIS Pro: Merge tables of geodatabases including existing joins

Tags: arcgis-pro, merge, attribute-joins, esri-geodatabase

Is there an option to keep existing `Joins` for the output of the `Data Management > Merge` process applied on multiple geodatabase files?

I have multiple geodatabase files `*.gdb` with the same structure, i.e. same tables, same fields, same `Joins` across their own tables, etc. The geodatabase files only differ in the content of the tables as they cover different spatial areas. Merge of the matching tables across the geodatabase files with `Data Management > Merge` works fine for the content of the tables. However, existing `Joins` do not exist in the final merged tables as they seem to get dropped during the merge process. Subsequent manual addition of the `Joins` reveals that the `Joins` are valid for the merged content as well.

Comment: Are your joins actually in the GDB feature class(es), or just in the layers?  Ie, describe how your joins are created/configured (and where/how you created configured the joins).  Please edit the original question to add this information.